# Failed to read android debug key

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, keystore

Trying to build my app which I could build with no issues 10 minutes ago and all of a sudden started getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
> Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/Users/quinn/.android/debug.keystore": DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
```

Haven't touched any of the code or touched the keystore - all I did was run some unit tests and then the key stopped working.

When i run `./gradlew --stacktrace` the build succeeds, but trying to build to any device and i get the error above.

Has this happened to anyone else / is there any way to fix this?

I've noticed that it is also only affecting one of my android projects - all my other android projects can build fine (and I assumed the same debug keystore was used for all of them)

Comment: Your 2nd Update worked for me as well. Please use it to answer you're own question and accept it so others find it more easily ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I feel dumb for not trying this earlier - after a couple hours of panic I got it to build by doing `Build -> Clean Project` first.