# ionic capacitor run android fails because of gradle keystore error

Tags: gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am trying to get my project running again after i reset my pc, but i am having troubles trying to live debug my ionic capacitor application.

When running this command
`ionic capacitor run android --warning-mode=all --stacktrace`
i get the following error:

```
? Which device would you like to target? Pixel 3 API 30 (emulator) (Pixel_3_API_30)
> ng.cmd run app:build
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

.....

Build at: 2022-06-18T16:13:14.915Z - Hash: 8e1052a90694f1cd - Time: 6805ms
> capacitor.cmd run android --target Pixel_3_API_30
[capacitor] √ Copying web assets from www to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 1.33s
[capacitor] √ Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 1.32ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 1 Cordova plugin for android:
[capacitor]        phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@8.1.0
[capacitor] √ copy android in 1.40s
[capacitor] √ Updating Android plugins in 7.78ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 4 Capacitor plugins for android:
[capacitor]        @capacitor/app@1.1.1
[capacitor]        @capacitor/haptics@1.1.4
[capacitor]        @capacitor/keyboard@1.2.2
[capacitor]        @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.8
[capacitor] [info] Found 1 Cordova plugin for android:
[capacitor]        phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@8.1.0
[capacitor] √ update android in 124.28ms
[capacitor] × Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] [error] 
[capacitor]         > Configure project :app
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
[capacitor]         It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[capacitor]         For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         > Configure project :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
[capacitor]         It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
[capacitor]         For more information, see http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html.
[capacitor]         WARNING::                             Using flatDirs should be avoided because it doesn't support any meta-data formats.
[capacitor]         Currently detected usages:
[capacitor]         - repository flatDir used in: project ':app', project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'
[capacitor]         - repository flatDir2 used in: project ':app', project ':capacitor-cordova-android-plugins'
[capacitor]         WARNING:: Please remove usages of `jcenter()` Maven repository from your build scripts and migrate your build to other Maven repositories.
[capacitor]         This repository is deprecated and it will be shut down in the future.
[capacitor]         See http://developer.android.com/r/tools/jcenter-end-of-service for more information.
[capacitor]         Currently detected usages in: root project 'android', project ':app', project ':capacitor-android', ...
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:writeDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:writeDebugAarMetadata
[capacitor]         > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugResValues
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugResources
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugResources
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:extractDeepLinksDebug
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:processDebugManifest
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugLibraryResources
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:parseDebugLocalResources
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugBuildConfig
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:javaPreCompileDebug
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugShaders
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:packageDebugAssets
[capacitor]         > Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:compressDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:syncDebugLibJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-android:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:syncDebugLibJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugJavaResource
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:syncDebugLibJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-haptics:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:syncDebugLibJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-keyboard:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:syncDebugLibJars UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-status-bar:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:generateDebugRFile
[capacitor]         > Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:extractDebugAnnotations
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:bundleLibRuntimeToJarDebug
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:syncDebugLibJars
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:bundleDebugAar
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:compileDebugSources
[capacitor]         > Task :capacitor-cordova-android-plugins:assembleDebug
[capacitor]         > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:dexBuilderDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]         > Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
[capacitor]         > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable  
[capacitor]         > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "C:\Users\maxgu\.android\debug.ked\debug.keystore": Invalid keystore format> Task :app:packageDebug FAILED
[capacitor]
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Try:
[capacitor]         Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[capacitor]
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[capacitor]         Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[capacitor]         See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[capacitor]         178 actionable tasks: 23 executed, 155 up-to-date
[capacitor]         BUILD FAILED in 4s
[capacitor]
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.

        capacitor.cmd run android --target Pixel_3_API_30 exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Sadly the stacktrace and warning-mode=all did not really give me info to work with. Does anyone know, what the problem could be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Invalid keystore format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66846074/how-to-solve-invalid-keystore-format)

Answer (score -1):

As mentoined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54879328/7937665), i deleted the file which was then recreated by running the `ionic capacitor run android` and then everything worked like a charm!